# SKReceiptRefreshRequest failed with ASDErrorDomain Code=530

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, storekit

In the sandbox, testing in-app-purchase on iPhone. There's no receipt, so I'm requesting a new one with the following.

```
func refreshReceipt() {
    let refresh = SKReceiptRefreshRequest()
    refresh.delegate = self;
    refresh.start()
}

func requestDidFinish(_ request: SKRequest) {
    print("Request did finish")
}

func request(_ request: SKRequest, didFailWithError error: Error) {
    print("Error: Store Request Failed: \(error.localizedDescription)")
}
```

I'm getting the following error.

```
<SKReceiptRefreshRequest: 0x283f34d40>: Finished refreshing receipt with error: Error Domain=ASDErrorDomain Code=530 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (ASDErrorDomain error 530.)" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The operation couldn’t be completed. (ASDErrorDomain error 530.)}

Error: Store Request Failed: An unknown error occurred
```

I'm not sure what is wrong and how to fix it. Really can't proceed without any receipt.

Comment: I've found the receipt refresh doesn't seem to work in Sandbox, however mostly my sandbox apps do have receipts after a purchase - is it pre-purcahse you are trying to check?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error and it was caused by the `SKReceiptRefreshRequest` timing out after 30 seconds while the login prompt for the App Store Sandbox account, which was triggered by the request, was being displayed.

This got our app rejected during app review and it was tricky to track down since it only happened in TestFlight when taking longer than 30 seconds to enter the credentials.

The solution was to call `cancel()` on any pending `SKReceiptRefreshRequest` and set a flag indicating that a request was interrupted during `applicationWillResignActive` and then start a new `SKReceiptRefreshRequest` during `applicationDidBecomeActive` if the flag indicates that a request had been interrupted.